# Changing font formattings of selected word/line in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-4.2

Has anyone tried to change the font formatting(bold/italic/color) of a selected word or sentence in a UITextView, like a text editor application? I have been trying to do this but it seems formatting is applied only to the whole text, not on individual words or sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITextView` cannot style text fragments. Styles, colors and fonts are applied to the *entire* text. You may wish to use a `UIWebView` or Core Text to render your text instead.

Comment: Accepted for CoreText...I am going with that option.

Answer (score 1):

you can change any specific word font, style and size also,

Make UITextView text to "Attributed", by default it was "Plain"
and then you can perform edition on selected text.