# how to change the color of the first text in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

is there a way where we can change the color of the first text in UITextView and the rest of the text will in default color which is black

Comment: What is "first text"? `UITextView` has only one `text` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can change the color of a word or sentence of a UITextView but not the entire content, the answer is no unfortunately.

Check this answer here, [Change font of individual words in UITextView in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561183/change-font-of-individual-words-in-uitextview-in-interface-builder)

It is possible to use a UIWebView to render the text in the manner you are asking. You could also draw it yourself using CoreText, but that would be quite a pain.

Hope this helps,
Matt